# How to get user id from Zend_Auth

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have big problem with getting user_id with zend..

My auth login code:

```
if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())){
        $adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
                null,
                'sprzedawca',
                'email',
                'haslo',
                'MD5(CONCAT(?, salt))'
        );

        $adapter->setIdentity($form->getValue('email'));
        $adapter->setCredential($form->getValue('haslo')); 

        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        $wynik = $auth->authenticate($adapter);

        if($wynik->isValid()){
            //return $this->_helper->FlashMessenger('Pomyślnie zalogowano');
            return $this->_helper->redirector(
                    'index',
                    'sprzedawca',
                    'default'
            );
```

Now when i try write user id using:

```
Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()
```

I got only 'username' but i want to get user_id

```
Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->user_id
```

doesn't work too..

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this through a Google search, try it.

```
Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->User_ID
```

Comment: tried and:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\spms\application\controllers\SprzedawcaController.php on line 33

Comment: Fair enough, sorry about that. it was just a guess I have no knowledge of this API? personally.

Answer (score 0):

okay, i didn't store item while loggin

Should be:

```
if($wynik->isValid()){
   $storage = $auth->getStorage();
   $storage->write($adapter->getResultRowObject('sprzedawca_id'));
```

and now works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your database Scheme now, but i can tell you that this has worked for me.

```
<?php 

    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $userId = $auth->getIdentity()->id;//user_id OR id depending your primary key of the user table.
    echo $userId;

 ?>
```

Attention:- $userId = $auth->getIdentity()->id; //id must written as it is your user table, other it  wise won't work